# Relative imports from __init__ in multi-file Django apps

Tags: python, django, import

I have a Django project located at /var/django/project/ where /var/django/ is in the PATH

within that project I have:

```
___init__.py
manage.py
utils/
    __init__.py
    tools.py
```

`utils/__init__.py` contains a function named `get_preview`

`utils/tools.py` contains a function named `get_related`

How can `utils/__init__.py` import `get_related` from `utils/tools.py`?

How can `utils/tools.py` import `get_preview` from `utils/__init_.py`?

I have tried relative imports as well as static imports but seem to get an error in `tools.py` when I try to `from project.utils import get_preview`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it, you just need to make one of the imports happen at runtime to avoid the circular import.

For example, `__init__.py`:

```
from project.utils.tools import get_related

def get_preview():
     # ...
```

and `tools.py`:

```
def get_related():
    from project.utils import get_preview
    # ...
    get_preview()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't (and shouldn't). You are structuring your code very poorly if files in your module are referencing code in the `__init__.py` associated with it. Either move both functions into `__init__.py` or both of them out of `__init__.py` or put them into separate modules. Those are your only options.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, this is bad structure. You gotta watch out here with creating a circular import between the two files. 
[About circular imports](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm).